# route that remains on the same page vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is the first time that this happens to me, when I click on the next button in the url bar the address changes but the page remains on the same as if I did not click on next. However, the new step is displayed below. I hope someone will have the solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<template>
    <div>
      <button @click="send" >next</button>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  methods:{
    send(){
   this.$router.push('/page/commande/1')
}
</script>

//router
{
    path:'/page/commande/1',
    name:'ConfirmationSend',
    component:() => import('../views/send.vue'),
  },
```

Comment: what does the current page have as path?

Comment: thanks @Boussadjra Brahim , path :'page/1'

Answer (score 3):

Hey you should add the key as fullPath of route in the router-view. As it will not re render the page/component only if the url params change.

```
<router-view :key='$route.fullPath' />
```

Comment: Thanks @Siva Chandran , I put the link like this: <router-view :key='$route.page/1' />. But the page does not appear. And if I do like this: <router-link :to="{ name: 'ConfirmationSend' }">  I have to refresh the page so that it is displayed

Comment: Hi Tony! You've misunderstood my answer. You have to use that as $route.fullPath only. You shouldn't change it as $route.page/1. You shouldn't refresh the page each time. It won't be an efficient way to achieve the result as refreshing the page will lead to refreshing all the state and data properties.

Comment: Hi @Siva Chandran, yes i think i misunderstood the answer. You mean that: I have to keep the full path from the beginning so as not to lose reactive data. That's right ? sorry if I do not understand right away. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: Hi @Siva Chandran I understood what you meant. I watched a lot of video on the router since yesterday. I looked on the browsing history, fullpaths etc ... thanks for getting me on the way

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I was able to work around the problem by adding an  tag in the template part and the method I put this. $ Router.push in order to be able to use my navigation guards. This is a temporary fix while you figure out what the real problem is. Thank you all for your help.